# Android - Re-inflating a fragment leads to "Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm all new to Android Development but already in big trouble. I've read several threads both here and on other sites regarding a similar or even the same problem. But all of the answers I've found don't fit my needs or aren't working for me at all.

So here's the thing. I'm having a single Activity with a self-made "menu" layer including 3 buttons at the bottom of the activity and a ScrollView above. Now on clicking one of those buttons I simply inflate a fragment into the ScrollView using

```
svContent.removeAllViews();
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_xyz, (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svContent));
```

which is inflated perfectly fine.

Now the inflated fragment includes another fragment for Google Maps (API 2), which looks like this.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

This fragment is also populated just the way I want on its parent fragment's inflation and the map is working fine.

Now I click on another menu button to have another fragment being inflated. But right when I click the button for the first fragment again, I get the following error:

> Duplicate id xxxxx, tag null, or parent id xxxxx with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Like I said, I've tried several solution I found online including

- moving from extending Fragment to FragmentActivity
- using SupportMapFragment instead of Fragment
- inflating the sub-fragment (the Google Maps one) from code instead of XML

All of these had several disadvantages I cannot accept at the moment (at least I think) or "didn't work" for me or in my constellation

Any help is greatly appreciated. And please me know if you need more information.

Regards,
D.

Comment: Why do you "cannot accept" creating the fragment by code ? It's 4 lines of code, it doesn't change anything and it would work perfectly.

Comment: Try moving to another constellation. Andromeda...maybe?

Comment: @StephaneMathis Creating the fragment from code is something I could perfectly accept but unfortunately didn't work for me - at least not the examples I've found while also looking through the api docs. I cannot remember the exact problem I had with it, I just had too many attempts at a solution the last 2 days. But of course I can try again, do you have a non-outdated working example?

Comment: Did you try replacing the fragment?

Comment: You have your own constellation? How do I get me one of those?

Comment: remove fragment when you navigate to another fragment.
have you remove fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the fragment in your ScrollView :

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.svContent, _mapFragment );
    ft.commit();
```

If you want to go back to the previous frgament with the back button, add `ft.addToBackStack(null);` before the commit.

And that's it.
By the way, you should probably not have a ScrollView as the container of your fragments. If the content must be scrollable, put the scroll in your fragment and put the fragment in a LinearLayout/FrameLayout/RelativeLayout.

Comment: Great, this hint combined with the comment by Code-Apprentice pushed me into the right direction. My problem was a structural one - mixing manual inflation with FragmentManager and regular Fragments with SupportFragments. Your input made me rework the fragment handling and obviously I now did it correct.

Answer (score 1):

To handle fragments, you should use the `FragmentManager`. This means that you should **not** inflate a fragment directly. Rather, you should allow the `FragmentManager` to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make map to null when user navigates to another screen.

destroy google map instance when onDestroy method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroyView() {
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fMap);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment);
        gMap.clear();
gMap = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```